# jQuery prevents radio button from being clicked

Tags: jquery

All,
I've got the following code to run through when a radio button is clicked to see if there is at least one entry in the group(s) choosen.

```
jQuery("input[type=radio]").click(function(event){
    alert('it is clicked');
    var num_questions = jQuery("#num_questions").val();
    var new_questions = parseInt(num_questions) + 1;
    for(var i=1; i<new_questions; i++){
        var radios = jQuery("input[type=radio]");
        var group  = radios.filter('[name=rating_value_'+i+']');
        if(group.filter(":checked").length==0){
            var answers_to_questions = "false";
            return false;
        }else{
            var answers_to_questions = "true";
            jQuery("#no_answers").html('');
        }
        //alert((group.filter(":checked").length)?"checked":"not checked");
    }
});
```

I get the alert so I know it's getting there, however, the radio button is not being checked. When I remove this code however, it works fine. Any ideas why this would cause this to happen?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you return `false` from the click handler that prevents the default click action from occurring. Also you really should move the `var radios = jQuery("input[type=radio]")` outside the `for` statement - no need to do that query again on every iteration.

Comment: can you provide a demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: You should remove all the code that is not used before posting. For example, `var answers_to_questoins`, etc. It will make it easier for people to provide a solution for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning `false` from an event handler prevents the default action for that event from occurring. In the case of a click on a radio button the default action is to select that radio button (and deselect the previously selected one in its group).

> *"when a radio button is clicked to see if there is at least one entry in the group(s) choosen"*

I can't understand what you're trying to achieve here. "at least one" doesn't make sense since only one radio at most can be checked in a given group. Less than one in a group can happen only if none were checked initially, because the user can't un-check all radios in a given group.

Having said that, in a general sense your code can be simplified:

```
jQuery("input[type=radio]").click(function(event){
    var num_questions = jQuery("#num_questions").val(),
        new_questions = parseInt(num_questions, 10) + 1,
        radios = jQuery("input[type=radio]"),
        all_answered = true;
    for(var i=1; i<new_questions; i++){
        if(radios.filter('[name=rating_value_'+i+']:checked').length===0){
            all_answered = false;
            break;
            // return false;   <------ don't return false or it cancels the click
        }
    }
    if (!all_answered) {
        // a group was found that didn't have an answer selected
        // so do something
    } else
        jQuery("#no_answers").html('');
});
```

Comment: I was trying to make it return false there since it found one that wasn't checked. How can I achieve that then because if it finds one that is false but then the last one is checked for example then it will think the overall thing is true and that's not the desired result.

Comment: OK, answer updated. This sets `all_answered` to `true` if all groups have an answer or to `false` if any group(s) have no answer. Or you could use the counter idea from Raminson's answer if you want to indicate exactly how many groups don't have an answer. Either way, the key thing is don't return `false` from the event handler.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$("input[type=radio]").click(function(event){
    var num_questions = parseInt($("#num_questions").val(), 10) + 1;
    var unselected = 0;
    for(var i = 1; i < new_questions; i++) {
        if ($('input[name=rating_value_'+i+']:checked').length == 0 ) {
             unselected++
        }
    }
    $("#no_answers").html('there are ' + unselected + ' radio groups');
});
```